# How to integrate yahoo music api with asp.net website using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone please suggest how to integrate yahoo music api in asp.net website?

thanks

Comment: Thats a bit open ended, how about a specific thing you want to integrate first?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend starting by looking at the API information that Yahoo supplies...
http://developer.yahoo.com/music/

After you've done that, if you have more of a specific question or problem, feel free to add another question here on SO with more details.

---

#### I found this information on their sites:

**3rd Party Downloads**
Here are other downloads provided by our enthusiastic developers.
(External links)
 1. [Yahoo! Music Jukebox Remote .NET 1.1 wrapper class and source](http://www.bliny.net/yahoo/ymj/YMERemote.html)
 2. [Yahoo! Music Jukebox plug-in VS 2003 project wizards](http://www.bliny.net/yahoo/ymj/VS2003Wizards.html)
*info from:* http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet

---